# Simple Graph representation in C#

Tags: c#, graph

I am new to C# programming and I am trying to implement graph ADT using adgecency list method. This is my representation of a graph:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Graph
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Graph
        {
            private int V;
            private int E;
            private List<List<int>> adj = new List<List<int>>();

            public Graph(int V0)
            {
                V = V0;
                E = 0;
                for(int v = 0; v < V0; v++)
                adj[v] = new List<int>();
            }

            public int getV() { return V; }
            public int getE() { return E; }

            public void addEdge(int v, int w)
            {
                adj[v].Add(w);   // Add w to v`s list
                adj[w].Add(v);   // add v to w`s list
                E++;
            }

            public string toStr()
            {
                string s = V.ToString() + "vertices, " + E.ToString() + "edges\n";
                for (int v = 0; v < V; v++ )
                {
                    s += v + ":";
                    foreach(int w in this.adj[v])
                        s += w.ToString() + " ";
                    s += '\n';
                }
                    return s;
            }


        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Graph g = new Graph(4);
            g.addEdge(0, 1);
            g.addEdge(0, 2);
            g.addEdge(0, 3);
            g.addEdge(1, 2);
            g.addEdge(2, 3);

            Console.WriteLine(g.toStr());

        }
    }
}
```

But when I compile it compiler denotes this line of code:

```
 adj[v] = new List<int>();
```

And throws a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. 
If anyone has any ideas what is wrong with my code I would appreciate it.

Comment: Just a hint: use properties instead of methods `public int GetV {get{return V;} set {V = value;}}`

Comment: Why not a Dictionary instead?
Because you are trying to use your list as a dictionary
Use string.Format instead of "aaa"+ "bbbb"
Use Environement.NewLine instead of "\n"

Comment: Instead of `toStr` you might want to override `ToString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `adj[v] = new List<int>();` yo're trying to set the element at position `v`. But `adj` is initially empty, you are receiving this exception because the position "v" is not valid.

Instead, You can add the new lists:

```
for(int v = 0; v < V0; v++)
    adj.Add(new List<int>())
```

Or if you want, change `adj` to array type and use your index version:

```
private List<int>[] adj;
...

public Graph(int V0)
{
    V = V0;
    E = 0;

    adj = new List<int>[V0];
    for(int v = 0; v < V0; v++)    
        adj[v] = new List<int>();
}
```

Comment: I'm usually not a fan of mixing arrays an lists, but in this case since the size of the outer collection is fixed when the `Graph` is created and the inner collections are dynamic in size it does make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the  sub lists because `adj` is empty at this point.

```
for(int v = 0; v < V0; v++)
    adj.Add(new List<int>());
```

Comment: Quoting [List<T>.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx): ***After** the list has been created and populated using the Add method, an element is **retrieved** and displayed using the Item property.*

Comment: This wont work, because he tries to use the variable v to set the second list.
v is used as index.
As I said in the comment, Dictionary would be a better approche in that case.

Comment: @pix That's why he should use `Add` instead of using `v` as an index.  Really `v` is only needed hear to keep track of how many adds have been done.  A Dictionary would only make sense here if the indexes were not sequential.

Comment: @pix `v` is local to the `for` loop. Has no other usage.

Comment: @Albireo 
for(int v = 0; v < V0; v++)
                adj[v] = new List<int>();

v is use as index into your list.
if the adj[1] is not set, you will get an out of range exception.

Comment: @pix That's the OP's code.  I'm telling them to use `Add` instead of trying to use an index into a list that is empty.

Comment: Add will work right, but he will loose the hability to set the list value.
for(int v = 0; v < V0; v++)
                adj[v] = new List<int>();
This is not the same as
for(int v = 0; v < V0; v++)
    adj.Add(new List<int>());

In his example v is use to reach a particulare element into the first list.
Not in your case.
Or did I miss something?

Comment: @pix Look at the code. He's setting the values in the constructor. `adj` is and always will be empty at that moment. @juharr is right.

Comment: @juharr: what about:  g.addEdge(0, 1);
            g.addEdge(1, 2);
            g.addEdge(3, 3);
            g.addEdge(0, 2);
            g.addEdge(2, 3);
            g.addEdge(2, 3);

if the first parameter is set, this is not for nothing.

Comment: @pix This code is just for setting up the List.  Once done `adj` will contain `V0` sub lists.  As for the `addEdge` it can then index `adj` because it now has sub lists in it, but if you do pass a value >= `V0` you would get an error, which should be expected.

Comment: @juharr : I totaly agree that your solution will work like a charm, but I think it can be improve :)
Your constructor must know the exact size of your list, this is not the softest approch :)